# Android: react-native-image-picker manifest.xml invalid file path

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

Sorry if i don't fully respect the question pattern, it is my first question on StackOverflow. :)

I am trying to run my react native app on Android (for the first time) after a long period of code (I was only testing on iOS).

I have been fixing a lot of issues mentioned by Android Studio but can't figure out the following one:

`error: invalid file path 'my_path/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android/build/intermediates/manifests/aapt/release/AndroidManifest.xml'.`

**My config:**

```
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.2"

"react-native": "0.56.0"
```

I have followed the path mentioned above, and the file exist and doesn't seem to have any error in it.

I also followed the install doc from **react-native-image-picker**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Have you added this dependency in settings and gradle file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do below steps to resolve.

`File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`